# Generating an RSA KeyPair and extracting modulus and exponent from Public Key in Android

Tags: android, rsa, public-key

I generated a Public Private Key Pair in Android. Now I need to send my Public Key back to the Server for communicating with RSA Encryption. However, I am communicating with a .NET Server (in C#). Therefore I need to send my Public Key in the following format:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>Modulus In Base 64</Modulus><Exponent>Exponent in Base 64</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

I generate the key Pair with the following code:

```
public static void generateKey() {

    try 
    {
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        privateKey = key.getPrivate();
        publicKey = key.getPublic();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I extract the modulus and exponent of the PublicKey I just generated?

Comment: Cast the public key to an `RSAPublicKey`, and from there retrieve and encode the parameters.

Comment: thanks I did that but is there any way that I can for example get the above mentioned format (in between RSAKeyValue tags> without doing it manually by retrieving and encoding the parameters?

Comment: Android's version of the java runtime doesn't contain much support for the XML digital signature standard, so you won't find much there to help.

Comment: thank you for your help, RSA between C Sharp and Android is not easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no native Android method to solve my problem. In order to extract the modulus and exponent of the generated Public Key, I used the following code, which takes an Android Public Key as Input and returns it in the .NET XML Format:

```
   public static String getPublicKeyAsXml(PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception

     {

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec ks = kf.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        BigInteger modulus = ks.getModulus();
        BigInteger exponent = ks.getPublicExponent();
        byte[] modByte = modulus.toByteArray();
        byte[] expByte = exponent.toByteArray();
        modByte = testBytes(modByte);
        expByte = testBytes(expByte);
        String encodedModulus = Base64.encodeToString(modByte, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String encodedExponent = Base64.encodeToString(expByte, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String publicKeyAsXML = "<RSAKeyValue>" +
                "<Modulus>" + encodedModulus + "</Modulus>" +
                "<Exponent>" + encodedExponent + "</Exponent>" +
                "</RSAKeyValue>";

        return publicKeyAsXML;
    }
```